Angular Standalone Component (using LoadComponent)- Lazy Loading Service not Working
The service is not working in the components. and have no error on the console. keep the component keep on loading. when I remove the service from component it start working fine. there is some issue in the lazy laod of service in the lazy load component. please help.
my service is Timingscreen.service.ts file
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TimingscreenService {}

my routing file is
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'timingscreen',
    loadComponent: () => import('./screens/timingscreen/timingscreen.component').then(c => c.TimingscreenComponent),
    title: 'Timing screen',
}]

and my component timingscreen.component.ts
import { Component, Inject, OnDestroy, OnInit, effect, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TimingscreenService } from '../../services/timingscreen.service';
        @Component({
      selector: 'app-timingscreen',
      standalone: true,
      imports: [],
      providers: [TimingscreenService],
      templateUrl: './timingscreen.component.html',
      styleUrl: './timingscreen.component.scss'
    })
    export class TimingscreenComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private timingService = inject(TimingscreenService)
    }


no need to have it in the providers when you use providedIn root;

@MatthieuRiegler  i remove { providedIn: 'root'}, but issue persist. the issue is actually when I go from localhost:4200 to localhost/timingscreen it works fine. but if I reload on localhost/timingscreen it stuck and keeps reloading. but when I remove the service from the component it then works on reload as well.

The issue was due to SSR. it has been fixed in my another question please have a look
Angular component not loading in the browser due to Observable subscription
